# Google App Engine write text string to blobstore without using deprecated API [Python]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have some pdf files uploaded to blobstore, i want to convert them to string and store them in blobstore as text files. I want to know how can i write a string (pdf converteed to text) into blobstore as a file. i know that  there is an API for it

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

but it has been deprecated . So what could be the possible alternative to it ?

Comment: That link explains what the alternative is.

Comment: yes, but its not for writing files to blobstore , it says write file to GCS. i was asking of a method that can be used to write files to Blobstore

Comment: But that's the point, writing files to Blobstore is deprecated, in favour of writing to GCS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just the API function you're looking for that's deprecated, it's the entire act of *writing to the Blobstore*. As the article you linked says, writes to the Blobstore are being deprecated in favour of writing to Google Cloud Storage, and simply using the Blobstore to serve files.

So unfortunately your question is "how do I do something that's deprecated without doing it in a deprecated way?" - you don't.